# Connecting dots from self-contained Java application to Mac OS installation

Tags: macos, deployment

I am not a Mac owner and am putting myself through a crash course to get up to speed (e.g., reading "Switching to the Mac"), to give you an indication of my current level of understanding. The access I have to a physical Mac is limited, so I am trying to connect as many dots as possible before my next session with my friend's computer.

I have: a file folder containing all resources needed for a self-contained application written with Java ([OpenJDK 11](http://jdk.java.net/11/), [JavaFX 11](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/)). The JLINK tool was successfully used to create this file folder, and it holds all necessary Java libraries as well as the code I wrote for the application. The executable resides in a subfolder: /bin. The program runs perfectly well on the Mac when the executable is run.

I want: something that is easy to download, install and run.

I'm unclear about what needs to be done to get this. The road map seems to have two main steps:

- the file folder needs to be converted into something that responds as if it were an application (e.g., a *Bundle*? or an .app?)
- the resulting folder-as-executable can be shipped via either .dmg or .pkg

For the second part, I've researched and found tools such as [Packages](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/documentation/Packages/en_2017/index.html) or [create-dmg](https://github.com/andreyvit/create-dmg). It seems to me these tools are pretty straightforward and shouldn't be too difficult to learn to use. (Just have to pick one or the other or something similar.)

For the first part, I'm on shaky conceptual ground. I've found info  [about Bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html), but no tutorials, walk-throughs or examples. It looks like a key step is understanding how to make a proper [Info.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html) file, but doing this properly looks tricky. Also, I'm not clear on how the resulting Bundle will become an .app file or if it needs to, or if there is another, more direct way to make my file folder be viewed by the OS as an application.

Some hand-holding or references to tutorials or even assurance that I am on the right track (if that is the case) would be much appreciated. Thanks!

The Java Deployment guide from Oracle relies heavily on ANT, but doesn't cover the case of a self-contained, customized JVM via JLINK well enough for me to decipher. So, I've taken the approach of trying to learn/understand the necessary steps using command-line commands.

Comment: The selected answer for the following question may be sufficient. Will test it soon. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224394/how-to-make-a-mac-os-x-app-with-a-shell-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating a Bundle is certainly an option, there is an easier way.

Step one is to make an .app manually. An answer to this question: "[How to make a Mac OS X .app with a shell script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224394/how-to-make-a-mac-os-x-app-with-a-shell-script)" goes over the basic steps. The Java file system that results from jlinking has a folder `/bin` in which there is a bash file that runs the program. This file should be moved to the outermost folder, and it should be named the desired name of the application. The bash file itself will have to be edited and "/bin" added to the address in last command so that the executable will be found. In addition, the folder itself will have to be renamed to be the same as the bash file, but with .app added as an extension.

The next thing I wanted to have was a custom icon. The question "[Include icon in manually created app bundle](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/352380/include-icon-in-manually-created-app-bundle)" shows how to do this.

For the next step I made use of the program "Packages". I'm a bit confused about where I downloaded this from (there seem to be multiple sites), but here is [a link to the manual](http://s.sudre.free.fr/Software/documentation/Packages/en_2017/index.html). This tool allowed me to create a .pkg file that, when executed, installs my .app in the Applications folder. Then I compressing the .pkg file (to .zip) and made it available at a URL for downloading.

I've had a friend do a test download and install, and the program works!

This isn't meant to be a complete tutorial, and there are a few steps more that I want to figure out pertaining to sandboxing and sealing, but I believe this is a reasonable roadmap that can be used for simpler jlinked Java applications for Mac distribution.